# Solve coupled partial differential equations with absorbing BCs

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method, boundary-conditions

I try to solve the following system of coupled equations with NDSolve but the results seem to be not correct. I attached my code in which five dependent variables $f_{1}$, $f_{2}$, $f_{3}$, $f_{4}$, and $f_{5}$ are coupled. I use NeumannValue to impose absorbing boundary conditions.

```
LL = 40;
A1 = 0.1584;
A2 = 23.8;
A3 = 2960;
A4 = 133.243;
A5 = 0.0001;
A6 = 7000;
A7 = 10^-3;
A8 = 0.278056;
A9 = 0.000482;
(*Set of Coupled Equations*)
eqn1 = -D[f1[t, x], t] + A1 D[f4[t, x], x, x] - A2 f4[t, x] - 
   A4 f2[t, x] + A5 D[f4[t, x], t];
eqn2 = -D[f2[t, x], t] - A1 D[f3[t, x], x, x] + A2 f3[t, x] + 
   A4 f1[t, x] - A5 D[f3[t, x], t] + A6 D[f5[t, x], x];
eqn3 = -D[f3[t, x], t] - (A2 + A3) f2[t, x] - A4 f4[t, x] + 
   A5 D[f2[t, x], t];
eqn4 = -D[f4[t, x], t] + (A2 + A3) f1[t, x] + A4 f3[t, x] - 
   A5 D[f1[t, x], t];
eqn5 = -D[f5[t, x], t, t] - A7 D[f5[t, x], t] + A8 D[f5[t, x], x, x] +
    A9 D[f3[t, x], x];
(*Boundary Conditions*)
Subscript[Γ, N1] = NeumannValue[-f1[t, x], True];
Subscript[Γ, N2] = NeumannValue[-f2[t, x], True];
Subscript[Γ, N3] = NeumannValue[-f3[t, x], True];
Subscript[Γ, N4] = NeumannValue[-f4[t, x], True];
Subscript[Γ, N5] = 
  NeumannValue[-Derivative[1, 0][f5][t, x], True];
(*Initial Conditions*)
ICs = {f1[0, x] == 0, f2[0, x] == Exp[-x^2/9], 
   f3[0, x] == 0, f4[0, x] == 0,
   f5[0, x] == 0, Derivative[1, 0][f5][0, x] == 0};
(*First Approach: Using NeummanValue Boundary Conditions*)
{F1, F2, F3, F4, F5} = 
  NDSolveValue[{eqn1 == -Subscript[Γ, N1], 
    eqn2 == -Subscript[Γ, N2], 
    eqn3 == -Subscript[Γ, N3], 
    eqn4 == -Subscript[Γ, N4], 
    eqn5 == -Subscript[Γ, N5], ICs},
   {f1, f2, f3, f4, f5}, {t, 0, 50}, {x, -LL, LL}, 
   Method -> {"MethodOfLines", 
     "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement"}}];
(*Animating the Results*)
ListAnimate[
 Table[Plot[F3[t, x], {x, -LL, LL}, PlotRange -> {-3,
   3}], {t, 0, 50, 0.25}]]
```

I would be grateful if anyone could help.

Comment: How you know correct result looks like?

Comment: I expect the excitation at the center and at the t=0 goes away from the center to the boundaries and finally being fully absorbed in the boundaries without any reflection. In the other words, I don't expect any waves in the domain (-LL,LL) in the long time limit.

Comment: Do you suppose non reflective boundary conditions? Also what is the meaning of `f6` in you code?

Comment: Right, I suppose absorbing(non-reflecting) boundary conditions. Sorry f6  was a typo and I fixed it.

Comment: Don't use same identificatory for numerical solution and variables, it could be better to put  `{F1, F2, F3, F4, F5}=NDSolveValue[...,{f1, f2, f3, f4, f5},...]`. Also why do you use so big scales `LL=125000, {t, 0, 500000}`?

Comment: Have you seen the section on [Absorbing Boundary Conditions](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/PDEModels/tutorial/Acoustics/AcousticsTimeDomain.html#481530965) in the Acoustics monographs? Also the ABC is applied on f5, why would expect it on f3? Think about the form of the source, plane wave, cylindircal, etc as that has an influence on the form of the ABC.

Comment: I've rescaled the parameters so now x runs from -40 to 40 and time goes up to 50.

Comment: The source is of gaussian type at t=0 which drives f2 out of equilibrium.